# Use Geocoder to calculate distance outside of rails

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rails-geocoder

The geocoder gem allows easy calculation of distance between 2 coordinates within rails:

```
obj.distance_from([40.714,-100.234])
```

How can I achieve this in a ruby script outside of rails?

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to assume the Earth is a sphere, then there's a straightforward formula to compute the distance between two points given their latitudes, longitudes, and the radius of the Earth:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance#Formulas

I've implemented it here (see `Point#distance`) without factoring in the radius of the Earth (or, you could say my unit of measurement is one Earth radius):

https://gist.github.com/amitkgupta/5019163

If you want results in meters, miles, etc. you'd need to multiply by the appropriate value for radius.